# El metodo split(" ") de un array me devuelve el array desordenado

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, método

Quiero guardar en un array el valor de un text area y lo estoy haciendo con un `let array = texto.split(" ")`, pero al hacer `console.log(array)` me lo devuelve desordenado. ¿que puedo hacer?

[image: Problema]

Acá el código:

```
let t_Area = document.querySelector("#texto") // Obtengo el tag textArea
let texto, array, letras, palabras, firstWord, lastWord, arrInverso, orden, ordenInverso

function leer() { // Función ejecutada al clickear el botón 'Enviar'
texto = t_Area.value // Obtengo el valor del textArea en el momento del click
array = texto.split(" ") // Separo el valor del textArea por espacios, me un array con las palabras
console.log(texto)
console.log(array)


letras = 0
palabras = array.length // El numero de palabras en el texto
firstWord = array[0] // Se obtiene la primera palabra
lastWord = array[array.length - 1] // Se obtiene la ultima palabra
arrInverso = array.reverse()
orden = array.sort()
ordenInverso = orden.reverse()

for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) { // El for se ejecuta según el número de palabras
    letras+= Number(array[i].length) // Calcula el total de letras, no cuenta los espacios
}

console.log("Hay " + letras + " letras") // Muestra el total de letras, no cuenta los espacios
console.log("Hay " + palabras + " palabras") // Muestra el total de palabras, no cuenta los espacios
console.log("La primera palabra es: " + firstWord) // Muestra la primera palabra del texto
console.log("La ultima palabra es: " + lastWord) // Muestra la ultima palabra del texto
console.log("El texto a la inversa es: " + arrInverso) // Muestra el texto inverso
console.log("El texto ordenado de la A a la Z es: " + orden) // Muestra el texto ordenado de la A a la Z
console.log("El texto ordenado de la Z a la A es: " + ordenInverso) // Muestra el texto ordenado de la Z a la A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El array aparece de manera correcta tan pronto haces el `split`.

Creo que los problemas que tienes ocurren después:

1. `arrInverso = array.reverse()` al ejecutar esto, estas ordenando de formar descendente el arreglo `array` y `arrInverso` se vuelve solo una referencia de la variable `array`.
2. `orden = array.sort()` el ejecutar esto, estas ordenando de forma ascendente el arreglo `array`, `arrInverso` y `orden` se vuelve una referencia de `array`.
3. `ordenInverso = orden.reverse()` al ejecutar esto, estar ordenando de forma descendente el arreglo `array`, `arrInverso` y `orden` y `ordenInverso` se vuelve una referencia de `orden` la cual es una referencia de `array`.

Verifica y prueba el siguiente código para que valides que los arreglos son iguales al realizarlo de la manera como lo hace tu código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#validar').click(function() {
  let arr = $('#text').val().split(' ');
  console.log('Array normal', arr);
  
  var ordenInverso = arr.reverse();
  console.log(arr, ordenInverso);
  
  var orden = ordenInverso.sort();
  console.log(arr, ordenInverso, orden);
  
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text" style="width: 100%;">hola una frase de ejemplo</textarea>
<button type="button" id="validar">Validar</button>
```

Para poder contar con variables que contengan arreglos diferentes, debes copiar el arreglo, utilizando cualquiera de las formas que se presentan en el código a continuación

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {

     $('#validar').click(function() {
      let arr = $('#text').val().split(' ');
      console.log('Array normal', arr);
      
      const copy1 = arr.slice();
      const copy2 = [].concat(arr);
      const copy3 = Object.values(arr);
      const copy4 = [...arr];
      const copy5 = Array.of(...arr);
      const copy6 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
      const copy7 = arr.map(i => i);
      const copy8 = Object.assign([],arr);
      
      copy1.reverse();
      console.log(arr, copy1);
      
      copy2.sort();
      console.log(arr, copy1, copy2);
      
     });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <textarea id="text" style="width: 100%;">hola una frase de ejemplo</textarea>
    <button type="button" id="validar">Validar</button>
```

Comment: Si me solucionó lo de ordenanr las palabras, pero cuando hago el array.split(" ") y luego hago un console log de eso, me lo saca todo desordenado, ve la imagen

Comment: Esto es porque modificas el array a travez de las lineas de código siguientes a esta linea "console.log(array)". En realidad el arreglo esta ordenado de forma descendente, ya que le haces un sort(), y luego un reverse(). Has esta prueba, comenta todas las lineas después de la línea 8 o después de esto "console.log(array)" y el array debería aparecer normal.